# python variable value to trigger parameter default

Tags: python, argument-passing

In Python, is there a value that a variable can be set to, so that when it is passed to a function the function will use the parameter's default value? For example:

```
def my_function( a = "default_value" ) :
    print a

my_function( my_variable )
```

Would print "default value". Would it be Pythonic to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally do *not* do this; you leave the parameter out altogether and leave it to python to fill in the default:

```
my_function()
```

You can retrieve the default values from a function with the [`inspect.getargspec()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec).

```
from inspect import getargspec

defaults = getargspec(my_function).defaults
my_variable = defaults[0]
my_function(my_variable)
```

Your example is rather simple of course; it only takes *one* argument that you know to have a  default value. In more common situations there are positional parameters too, which do not have defaults.

To reconstruct what arguments have defaults, you need to re-combine the arguments and their defaults:

```
argspec = getargspec(my_function)
keyword_args = dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
positional_args = [None] * (len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults))  # set all positionals to None
my_function(*positional_args, **keyword_args)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from inspect import getargspec
>>> defaults = getargspec(my_function).defaults
>>> my_variable = defaults[0]
>>> my_function(my_variable)
default_value
>>> argspec = getargspec(my_function)
>>> keyword_args = dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
>>> positional_args = [None] * (len(argspec.args) - len(argspec.defaults))  # set all positionals to None
>>> my_function(*positional_args, **keyword_args)
default_value
>>> keyword_args
{'a': 'default_value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom for using default arguments, aside from just not passing the value is to set the parameter to default to None and then use the default value if it's `None`, e.g.:

```
def my_function(a=None):
    if a is None:
       a = "default_value"
    print a
```

Then you can pass `None` to the function and it won't kill the default argument.

```
my_variable = None
my_function(my_variable) # prints 'default_value'
```

You might want to do this if you have multiple functions with similar signatures, e.g.:

```
def func1(a=None, b=None):
    print b
    func2(a)

def func2(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = 'default value'
    print a
```